# Number formatting in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SSRS 2008 reports are being developed using T-SQL Queries. The requirement is to display the numbers in Indian format. E.g 1234568 should be shown as 12,34,568. SSRS is applying thousand seperator(i.e 1234568 is shown as 1,234,568) only, though number format is set to regional settings for all the report items and the regional settings in report server machine are set to the required format. We tried custom formats also but invain. Is there is any solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help?

http://agilebi.com/cs/blogs/jwelch/archive/2008/12/16/formatting-numbers-in-ssrs-and-ssas.aspx

social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/836141dd-097f-402e-ae95-f561cbf3b6c6/

Comment: The first link did not help because it spells out a way to show numbers in 10K instead of 1K. The custom code outlined in the second link helped me. Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but would changing the region settings also be a possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

This may also be helpful:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/5e2c8681-9d7d-4731-848e-d0e2cc8aa0b7

Answer (score 0):

in the field value use like `=Format(Fields!ServiceTaxAmt.Value,"##,##,##,###.00")` and change the language value to `hi-in` for report property.